# Property read only error when setting the label location for the axes - Infragistics

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I am building the xamdatachart axes in the code behind as below:

```
NumericYAxis yAxis = new NumericYAxis() { IsInverted=true, MajorStrokeThickness= 0 }; 
NumericYAxis yAxis_right = new NumericYAxis() { IsInverted = false, MajorStrokeThickness = 0 };
```

To set yAxis's location to OutsideLeft and yAxis_right's location to OutsideRight, I added following part:

```
yAxis.MinimumValue = 0;
yAxis.Title = "Depth";
yAxis.LabelSettings.Location = AxisLabelsLocation.OutsideLeft;

yAxis_right.MinimumValue = 0;
yAxis_right.Title = "Net Production";
yAxis_right.LabelSettings.Location = AxisLabelsLocation.OutsideRight;
```

But get error as

> "Cannot set a property on object 'Infragistics.Controls.Charts.AxisLabelSettings' because it is in a read-only state."

Any insights on why it happens?

I found [this link](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2015.1/CLR4.0/html/DataChart_Multiple_Axes.html) useful from their website and I did follow the same but I get above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue in Xamdatachart.
here is the Infragistics's response and workaround to it.

*This is essentially due to the AxisLabelSettings object being frozen, and so it gets placed in a read-only state. The workaround to this issue is to create a new AxisLabelSettings object and assign it to your axes' LabelSettings property. You can use the following code for this:*

```
AxisLabelSettings settings = new AxisLabelSettings() { Location = AxisLabelsLocation.OutsideRight };
yAxis.LabelSettings = settings;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is being thrown because some property in LabelSettings is read-only aka get-only property. From your code, only Location property is being assigned so i would believe that property doesn't have a public set, causing an error when you try.

I searched for NumericYAxis class and found this:

http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/wpf/2012.1/clr4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.v12.1~Infragistics.Controls.Charts.AxisLabelSettings~LocationProperty.html

So Location is both a Dependency property (and this is static read-only) and a also the name of a member property (with get and set). When you type yAxis_right.LabelSettings.Location only one suggestion appears in Visual Studio?